# Adding Contacts to Group from an Activity Report doesn't work on Joomla! 4?

Tags: joomla, civireport, activities

I see the possibility of adding contacts to a group from an activity report.
After posting the list, I select the group from the drop-down menu on the right, I have to confirm by clicking Next and then a confirmation message appears at the top right.
But when I display the band, I see no added contact.

I activate the debug mode but I cannot see any error message.
Where can I find system logs or something?

I use CiviCRM 5.71.1 with Joomla!4

Secondary question: in a CiviCRM instance with Joomla! 4, I see this possibility of adding contacts to a group from an activity report. In another instance, I don't see it. How to activate it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find details about where to find the system logs in the SysAdmin guide:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#review-the-civicrm-log